# Reason for not being able to use DISTINCT more than once in SQL

Tags: sql, database, distinct

I know that you can use DISTINCT with multiple columns and not use it more than once in a single SQL query, but what is the reason for this ? I could think of the case that the output of SQL is rows and applying distinct on 2 columns seperately would result in a conflict of which rows to output but is there any more to it? Perhaps someone could clarify this.

This is common for many SQL implementations(I have tried MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite). An example query would be like

SELECT DISTINCT(column1), DISTINCT(column2) FROM table;

Comment: thanks for the tip, i just edited it, hope its better now

Comment: Maybe you can also share sample input data along with the output you want to see.

Comment: thats the interesting part, to my knowledge i know that its not possible and i want to know if my reasoning is correct, however if thats not the case maybe someone can think of a sample output, a sample input table can be as simple as alphabet(A,A,B,B,C,D) , digit(0,0,1,2,3,1)

Comment: Yes, you’re reasoning is correct